# Getting the Average of an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this an assignment where the user has to enter in a name, then a score, and repeat that process until they are done, press Q, and then the array will show the names and scores, then give an average of all of those scores. What I have right now is this.

```
    static void inputPartInformation(string[] pl, double[] sc)
    {

        int i = 0;

        do
        {
            Console.Write("Enter The Player's Name: ");

            pl[i] = Console.ReadLine();


            Console.Write("Enter Their Score: ");

            sc[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }
        while (pl[i++].CompareTo("Q") != 0);

    }


    static void displayParts(string[] pl, double[] sc)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (pl[i].CompareTo("Q") != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,15}{1,6}", pl[i], sc[i]);
            ++i;
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String[] players = new String[100];

        double[] scores = new double[100];

        inputPartInformation(players, scores);



        displayParts(players, scores);


        double average = scores.Average();
        Console.WriteLine("The Average is: {0}", average);



        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

When I try to average the scores, it doesn't come out properly.

Comment: Dunno much about C# but the average in general will be all of the values in the array added together divided by the length of the array.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't come out properly", how does it come out?  Does it throw an exception?  If it prints the wrong value, what value are you expecting and what's your input data that you're expecting this value from?

Comment: I input
David
123
Milo
321
The total score is 444 and the average should be 222, but it comes out as 4.44

Comment: Don't mind that looping "Welcome to" output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the call of `Average`: you are averaging everything, not everything up to the `"Q"` in the corresponding `names` position. You are adding together all these zeros in the scores part to which you did not write, and then divide it by 100 - the length of the entire array.

The easiest way to address this issue is to return the position of the `"Q"` entry from the `inputPartInformation` method:

```
var count = inputPartInformation(players, scores);
```

Now you can use LINQ's `Take` function to get the correct average:

```
double average = scores.Take(count).Average();
```

Comment: Ooh, so the ("Q") !=0 is the part that's tripping it up?

Comment: @user1580598 No, it is the fact that you are calling `double average = scores.Average();` on the entire `scores`, rather than on the first `N` items up to the `"Q"` entry.

Comment: "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable" towards the var count.

Comment: @user1580598 Oh, of course you need to modify your `inputPartInformation` method to return the count (it's `i-1` or something). This is tagged as "homework", so I should not be writing too much code for you.

Comment: .____. I've only been coding for about 12 days...I have no clue what the hell anyone is talking about.

Comment: @user1580598 OK then, change your `static void inputPartInformation` to `static int inputPartInformation`, and add `return i-1;` to the end of the function, after the `do / while` block. This will do the trick.

Comment: @___@ So i is the count, and then you are subtracking 1 because of the Q? Right?

Comment: @user1580598 Yes, this is correct: since you post-increment `i` after detecting your `"Q"`, you need to subtract `1` back to get the actual count.

Comment: Thanks. I really wish this class wasn't so "accelerated" This is my first coding class and we are seriously missing out on the very basics and instead learning "Here's what to do" instead of "here's what this does."

Comment: @user1580598 You are welcome! If you would like to try your hand at a related exercise, see if you can change `void displayParts(string[] pl, double[] sc)` to `void displayParts(int count, string[] pl, double[] sc)` and make your code slightly more readable (hint: the check for the `"Q"` is going away).

Comment: Well how about this example? I currently have a program that orders input names in alphabetical order. Everything is working except when I enter Q, the Q shows up in the output as well. It has a very simimlar format to this.

Comment: @user1580598 This is very much related to the exercise with `void displayParts(int count, string[] pl, double[] sc)`: once you change your method to this format, you will be able to use [`Array.Sort<K,V>(K[] keys, V[] values, int from, int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyzk314y.aspx), which will not be considering the entries with the `"Q"` because it's past the `count`.

Comment: Oh wait, I remember that there was more than just that problem @__@ I need to make a new question for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you count how many scores have been entered (in a variable `N`) and use the `.Take(N)` function to only return an array of `N` scores.

Example:

```
double[] list = new double[100];
// assumed first N values are filled only.
// N = ...
list = list.Take(N).ToArray();

double average = list.Average();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use an array?  Using a List may be a better choice as you simply add onto it as long as they keep adding scores.  That way when they quit and you go to take the average, it won't contain any 0's that are not entered scores.